# Rails 6 Second Database without Run Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

Recently try Rails 6 feature for multiple database :
With `database.yml` like this

```
development:
  primary:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    username: hoho
    password: hoho
    host: X.X.X.X
    port: 5432
    pool: 5
    database: hoho_development
  secondary:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    username: haha
    password: haha
    host: Y.Y.Y.Y
    port: 5432
    pool: 5
    database: haha_development
    migrations_paths: db/secondary_migrate
```

although `db/secondary_migrate` is empty..when i execute `rails db:migrate`, it still write `ar_internal_metadata` and `schema_migrations`.

is there any way to avoid this? in my usecase i don't want to write any new table to the second database, just want to read and write to existing tables that created not from rails migration.

Comment: IMHO I would just create the `ar_internal_metadata` table. Its just used to store a string containing the environment that the db was created in so that you don't accidentally connect to  your production database from test or development and wipe it.